# How parse multiple parameters in JSON?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have JSON in a PostgreSQL table as:

```
{"inputs": [{"desc": "How many people does the video contain?", "name": "Number of People", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Only 1", "2-3", "3+"]}, {"desc": "What is the camera position?", "name": "Movement", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Fixed position", "Moving"]}, {"desc": "From which angle did you shoot the video?", "name": "Shoot Angle", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Frontal recording", "Tight angle: 10-40 degree", "Wide angle: 40-70 degree"]}, {"desc": "From which distance did you shoot the video?", "name": "Distance", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Near/Selfie", "Mid (3-6 ft)", "Far (>6 ft)"]}, {"desc": "What is the video lighting direction?", "name": "Lighting Direction", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Front lit", "Side lit", "Back lit"]}, {"desc": "What is the video background?", "name": "Background", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Outdoors", "In office", "At home", "Plain background"]}, {"desc": "What is the topic in your speech?", "name": "Topic", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Arts and Media", "Business", "Education", "Entertainment", "Food/Eating", "Nutrition", "Healthcare ", "High School Life", "Mental Health", "News", "Technology", "Morals and Ethics", "Phones and Apps", "Sports", "Science"]}]}
```

This JSON contains multiple "name" keys (and others keys).

How I can parse values for every "name" keys?

I try:

```
SELECT
        s.projectid,
        s.prompttype,
        s.inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,desc}' AS desc,
        s.inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,name}' AS name,
        s.inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,values}' AS values,
        s.created,
        s.modified
FROM source_redshift.staticprompts AS s;
```

but I get only one value of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the jsonb array as such. With `{inputs,0,...}` you're retrieving only the first element of the jsonb array. Use `jsonb_array_elements` instead:

```
SELECT
  s.projectid,
  s.prompttype,
  el.inputs->>'name',
  el.inputs->>'desc',
  el.inputs->>'values',
  s.created,
  s.modified
FROM staticprompts AS s, 
     jsonb_array_elements(s.inputs->'inputs') el(inputs);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2c544529920ade3e81d0f594213c300)

Comment: No need for the usage of LATERAL, query works fine without it.

Comment: @FrankHeikens that's true! That's what happened when you reuse code :-D thanks for pointing out

Comment: Guys, I get an error: [42883] ERROR: function jsonb_array_elements(character varying) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk it means `s.inputs` isn't of type `jsonb`. You will need to cast it: `jsonb_array_elements(s.inputs::jsonb->'inputs')`